# heating elements

Tags: resistance

Is my (layman's) understanding correct, that the same resistance-type heating element can be driven by single-phase 120V or 240V current; that a different design is not required, one for each voltage, for example, a heavier gauge for the 240V?  As I understand it (but please correct me if I'm wrong), the difference is that the same element on 240V will draw half the amps that would be drawn if it were powered by 120V.

Comment: One rated for 240Vcan certainly be run at half voltage for less power, but not the reverse if the element temp is too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit garbled. Let's see if we can make sense of it.

- Power in a resistor is given by \$ P = VI \$ where *P* is power (watts or W), *V* is voltage (volts or V) and *I* is current (amps or A).
- A given power rating, e.g. 100 W, can be achieved at 100 V x 1 A, 200 V x 0.5 A, etc. The manufacturer will choose a suitable resistance wire to achieve this.
- We can calculate the resistance required for our heater by rearranging Ohms's Law to \$ R = \frac {V}{I} \$. For our 100 W, 100 V heater we get \$ R = \frac {100}{1} = 100 \; \Omega \$. For the 200 V model we get \$ R = \frac {200}{0.5} = 400 \; \Omega \$.

The part to watch is that power for a given resistor is proportional to the *square* of the voltage or current. So if we run the 100 V model on 200 V we will get 400 W output. Conversely, if we run the 200 V model on 100 V we will get 1/4 power or only 25 W.

> [From comments:] I'm trying to understand, from a consumer's perspective, not an engineer's, how a European company with a 240V kitchen 240V, let's call it a "countertop air cooking appliance", with a 2400W heating element, will be able to adapt that appliance to the US market with 120V. Wouldn't it max out a 120V 20A circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgtTLa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Dual voltage heater arrangement.*

The appliance would be configured with two elements and a wiring option. Connect the two elements in series for 240 V operation and in parallel for 110 V operation. Let's check the maths:

- For 1200 W at 120 V we will draw 10 A.
- If we connect the two elements in series the same 10 A will run through both elements but we'll need to double the voltage to do it. So 240 V x 10 A = 2400 W.
- If we connect the two elements in parallel then each branch will draw 10 A so 20 A in total. So 120 V x 20 A = 2400 W.

Comment: I fixed a typo in my comment (should read "240V kitchen appliance"). We were typing at the same time.

Comment: I need to do a little reading on the difference between "in series" and "in parallel".  Back at the circuit breaker, does it make a difference? Would two such 1200W elements running simultaneously in parallel on the same 20A circuit max it out?

Comment: Some homework: \$ P = VI \$. If the power is the same and the voltage doubles then what happens the current?

Comment: I don't have my head around "power" yet.  Is it a synonym for "energy"?

Comment: @TRomano, power is how quickly energy is moved or transformed.

Comment: @TRomano, But this is a **really** basic question, you could probably find the answer on physics.SE or wikipedia.

Comment: @Transistor: What I'm not grasping at the moment is whether the wiring in parallel addresses this issue: "...if we run the 200 V model on 100 V we will get 1/4 power or only 25 W."  Does that reduction mean that the US model of this appliance will have only (1/4 + 1/4) or half the power of the European one, unless changes are also made to increase the resistance of the heating element?

Comment: I added some voltmeters and additional text. Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

A heating element would draw half as much current at 120 volts as at 240 volts, and consume one quarter of the power.

For a given power, a 240 volt heating element would have a thinner resistance wire (for higher resistance) than a 120 volt element.

Current, voltage and resistance are related by Ohm's Law: E = I x R (E = voltage or electromotive force, I = current, and R = resistance in Ohms.)

Answer (score 2):

If your heating element is a dumb resistor then:

I = V/R

Thus the same resistor will draw 2x the current on 240V versus 120V. It's the same resistor, so the value of R does not change. Since

P = V*I = V^2/R

it will also burn 4x the power on 240V versus 120V.

So you can use a 240V heater on 120V, it will just heat 4x less. Using a 120V heater on 240V will work also... if we neglect small details like insulation voltage ratings... however it will burn 4x the power and since that was most likely not intended by the designers, the likelihood of firemen being involved at some point increases.

There are other smarter resistors (ie, PTC) whose resistance increases as they get hot, so they kinda regulate the power they draw, but they're not very common.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, from a consumer's perspective, not an engineer's, how a European company with a 240V kitchen appliance, let's call it a "countertop air cooking appliance", with a 2400W heating element, will be able to adapt that appliance to the US market with 120V.  Wouldn't 2400W element max out a 120V 20A circuit?

Comment: You wouldn't want to put a 2400Watt load on a 120V line.  Americans do have 240VAC in their houses, so you could put a 240 VAC outlet in a room if you really need it.  They run dryers and electric stoves/ovens on 240VAC, as well as welders.

Comment: @TRomano, Yes but my understanding is that (ordinary convenience) circuits in 240-V countries are typically limited to less than 10 A, so wouldn't there also be an issue getting 2400 W in Europe?

Comment: Also, 20-A circuits are not common in residences in North America. 15 A is the limit on the typical circuit available on the kitchen counter.

Comment: Usual rating here (France) is 230V 16A for wall sockets and other general purpose circuits. So 3.6kW. Of course several sockets are grouped on one 16A circuit breaker, so the limit is both per socket (due to socket design etc) and per circuit. For a big cooking stove you'd run a 20A or 32A dedicated line, no socket, the equipment will have wire terminals. Most likely the wire is already there as NFC15100 norm makes it mandatory to have it in the kitchen in all new construction.

Comment: For example my induction cooker has 2 live terminals so it can be used on 230V (just connect both to live) and three phase (using only two phases though). It's 7.5kW so it has its own 32A circuit breaker and wires.

Comment: @Photon: I believe it is now fairly common to find 20A circuits in kitchens and baths in the US.

Comment: @TRomano, AFAIK, even if the circuit is rated for 20 A, the individual power outlets will still be the 15 A type. See [this q&a](https://www.bobvila.com/posts/76903-15-amp-vs-20-amp-outlets?page=1#.WZhkjSiGNPY) for more info. Note that Q&A is 14 years old, but if you're actually thinking of marketing a 20-A appliance remember that many of the homes of your potential customers are that old and older.

Comment: @The Photon: You are right that in many older houses the outlets will be 15A but in kitchens and baths 20A circuits and outlets are required by code in all new construction and remodels.

Comment: If you're designing a product, do you want to sell it only to people whose house was built in the last 10 years? I've never run into a consumer product in the US that had a 20 A plug on it.

Comment: 20A small appliance circuits are required for kitchen counter circuits under US National Electrical Code. A 2400W Load would overload the circuit as NEC also specifies that a circuit breaker not be loaded beyond 80% of it's capacity. Under the NEC one would have to run a 30A circuit to handle that load.