# Are heating elements multi voltage?

Tags: voltage, heat, step-down

I have a 110 volt crock pot but I live in a 220 volt country. It says it uses 270 watts.

Can I just use it anyways without modification or should I try to find the interal wiring and make the heating elements in series instead of in parallel as explained in here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/324745/100185 ?

I want to avoid having to use a step down converter.

Comment: Does the crock pot have any indication on it that it can be adjusted to work on 220 V? If not, the safest option is to buy one which works on 220 V. (If you plug it in as-is, it will consume about 1000 W for a brief time before either burning out or catching on fire, if it has no fast-acting over-current or over-temperature protection.)

Comment: Reduce voltage easier than increase. There is a lot of converters with just diode or capacitor inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Simple crock pots are just a resistive element with a thermostat.  It will overheat.  More complicated crock pots have electronic timers.  If the power supply for those electronics are designed for 110V, then they will likely burn out at 220V.

Comment: More specifically, applying double voltage will make it draw double amperage (assuming simple resistive load) and thus draw **four times** the power (wattage) and four times the heat. It will quickly burn out and may start a fire!